# What's the way how to properly put a question to a given words?

Tags: questions, present-simple, who-whom

I've just taken an online test where I didn't get scores in several tasks. So, I was wondering if this is because of my mistakes or there is an issue with the test.

Could somebody take a look and correct me if there is something wrong with my answers?

Thanks in advance.

**Put the questions to the highlighted words.**

> We often meet **them**.

Answer: *Whom do we often meet? (or maybe "Whom do we meet often?")*

I'm not sure if I should use **who** or **whom** here. And also, don't know the I placed **often** in the correct place.

**Put the questions to the highlighted words. Pay attention to the position of the preposition:**

> She listens to **the lector** very attentively.

Answer: *Whom does she listen very attentively to?*

> Our colleagues are ready for **your questions**.

Answer: *What our colleagues are ready for?*

> My friend often discusses his problems with **his groupmates**.

Answer: *Whom does my friend often discuss his problems with?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to speak English, or pass the test.

If you want to pass the test you need to find out what is being tested.

In standard English, "Whom" is hardly ever used. It is old fashioned, except with a prepostion  for example "To whom...".  It might be that the test is finding if you can form questions naturally, or it might be testing if you have read an old grammar book which uses the old form "whom" for the object case.

In natural Engish all the questions above are asked with "Who".

> Who do you often meet?
> Who does she listen to?

In some versions of "grammar book English" the object form is whom, and one "pays attention to the position of the preposition"

> Whom do you often meet?
> To whom does she listen?

If this is what the test expects you to write, get a better test. This is not standard modern English.